# NetworkX Minimum Spanning Tree has different cluster arrangement with the same data?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a large dataset which compares products with a relatedness measure which looks like this:

```
product1      product2  relatedness
0101          0102      0.047619
0101          0103      0.023810
0101          0104      0.095238
0101          0105      0.214286
0101          0106      0.047619
...           ...       ...
```

I used the following code to feed the data into the NetworkX graphing tool and produce an MST diagram:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

products = (data['product1'])
products = list(dict.fromkeys(products))
products = sorted(products)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(products)
print(G.number_of_nodes())
print(G.nodes())

row = 0
for c in data['product1']:
    p = data['product2'][row]
    w = data['relatedness'][row]
    if w > 0:
        G.add_edge(c,p, weight=w, with_labels=True)
    row = row + 1

nx.draw(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The resulting diagram looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBrnD.jpg

However, when I re-run the code, with the same data and no modifications, the arrangement of the clusters appears to change, so it then looks different, example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR62Q.jpg, second example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLHyo.jpg. The clusters, edges, and weights do not appear to be changing, but the arrangement of them on the graph space is changing each time.

What causes the arrangement of the nodes to change each time without any changes to the code or data? How can I re-write this code to produce a network diagram with approximately the same arrangement of nodes and edges for the same data each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nx.draw` method uses by default the `spring_layout` [(link to the doc)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html?highlight=spring%20layout#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout). This layout implements the [**Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) which starts with **random** initial positions. This is this layout effect that you witness in your repetitive trials.

If you want to "fix" the positions, then you should explicitely call the `spring_layout` function and specify the initial positions in the `pos` argument.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this, I tried adding this code: `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()`
but this seems to scramble the locations of the nodes even more: https://i.imgur.com/zlbqKN5.jpg
What additional arguments can I use with `spring_layout` to encourage the graphing tool to display the diagram in approximately the same way?

Comment: Why not pos=nx.spring_layout(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)) with nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G) in spite of G?

Comment: I changed the code so that it ends with `pos=nx.spring_layout(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G))
nx.draw(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()`, ran it twice, and it gave me this: https://i.imgur.com/PQVqDkB.jpg, followed by this: https://i.imgur.com/2g8BsAx.jpg. So it appears to still have the same problem, what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Each time you run the instruction ```pos=nx.spring_layout(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G))``` new positions are computed. Alternatively you can define a random seed like ```pos=nx.spring_layout(G = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), seed=1)``` or any other seed where the layout pleases you.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, setting the seed to be the same each time produce exactly the result I was hoping for, thank you for this, if you add that as a new answer I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Assign `G = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)` for purpose of clarity. Then

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

is equivalent to

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
```

Since you don't like `pos` to be calculated randomly every time you run your script, the only way to keep your `pos` stable is to store it once and retrieve from file after each rerun. You can put this script to calculate `pos` in an improved manner before `nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)`:

```
import os, json

def store(pos):
    #form of dictionary to be stored dictionary retrieved
    return {k: v.tolist() for k, v in pos.items()}
def retrieve(pos):
    #form of dictionary to be retrieved
    return {float(k): v for k, v in pos.items()}

if 'nodes.txt' in os.listdir():
    json_file = open('pos.txt').read()
    pos = retrieve(json.loads(json_file)) #retrieving dictionary from file
    print('retrieve', pos)
else:
    with open('pos.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        pos = nx.spring_layout(new_G) #calculates pos
        print('store', pos)
        json.dump(store(pos), outfile, indent=4) #records pos dictionary into file
```

This is an ugly solution because it depends unconditionally of data types used in `pos` dictionary. It worked for me, but you might to define your custom ones used in `store` and `retrieve`

Comment: Wow, this is an impressive solution too! I have a couple of questions, can I combine this approach with the solution from @Tone above to save the position values from a particular seed? Secondly, can I modify the position values in this file to change the fixed arrangement of the nodes?

Comment: For sure you can both cases. Just don't hesitate to experiment by trial an error. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: I managed to get your solution working for the same dataset, but I have multiple datasets associated with sequential years of data and I don't seem to be able to arrange the nodes in approximately the same way across different years, I think my code must be overwriting the pos.txt file each time

Comment: It actually attempts to extract a `pos` value from file named 'pos.txt' and if it is not found, calculates a new `pos` value and saves it in 'pos.txt'. If you change a dataset, you should either use a different filename or delete it before run. That's why I called my code ugly: it can't be customised in a flexible way.

Comment: It may be complicated to use the same `pos` value for different datasets.